# best way to ensure state is not null before passing the state as props?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, state

I currently have a generic component MapComp which is used to render polyline data on maps. I am trying to pass polyline data which I update through a state after a call to a function inside my Mapp component. The issue is that the state doesn't seem to be updating initially which is passing a null props value to my mapComp component which then causes an error for the getInitialPos() function as that is called when componenet loads to get the first position.
Is there a way for me to ensure my polylines state is defined 100% before the MapComp component is returned so that the props passed are not null. Or is there a better way for me to get the initialPos? I even tried without the useEffect in MapComp too but nothing has worked.

MapComp:

```
import react from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Popup, Polyline} from 'react-leaflet';
import polyline from '@mapbox/polyline';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MapComp(props) {

        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

        let initPosLat;
        let initPosLong;

    useEffect(() => {
        getInitPosition();
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log("props = ", props);
    }, [props])


    function getInitPosition() {
        console.log("props activity data = ", props);
        if(!Array.isArray(props.activityData)) {

            return [props.activityData.positions[0][0],props.activityData.positions[0][1]];
        
        }
        else {
            
          
            return [props.activityData.poylines.positions[0][0],props.activityData.poylines.positions[0][1]];
        }   
    }
    

    return (
        !isLoading ?
         <MapContainer center={getInitPosition()} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={props.style}>
            <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
                        
                {!Array.isArray(props.activityData) && <Polyline positions={props.activityData.positions} >
                    <Popup>
                        <div>
                            <h2>{"Name: " + + props.activityData.name}</h2>
                        </div>
                    </Popup>
                </Polyline>
                }

            {Array.isArray(props.activityData.polylines) && props.activityData.polylines.length > 1 && 
                
                props.activityData.polylines.map((activity, idx) => (
                    <Polyline key={idx} positions={activity.positions}>
                        <Popup>
                            <div>
                                <h2>{"Name: " + activity.name}</h2>    
                            </div>    
                        </Popup>    
                    </Polyline>
                ))}

                
        </MapContainer>
        : <div>
        <p>
        Loading...</p></div>
    )
}


export default MapComp;
```

Mapp component:

```
import react from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Popup, Polyline} from 'react-leaflet';
import axios from 'axios';
import polyline from '@mapbox/polyline';
import MapComp from './MapComp';


function Mapp() {

    const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
    const [polylines, setPolylines] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);



useEffect(() => { 
    setActivitieData();
      
      
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(activities.length) {
        setPolylineArray();
        
        console.log("Polylines in useEffect =", polylines)
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
    

}, [activities])


  const getActivityData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:8800/api/"
    );
    
    return response.data;
  };

    const setActivitieData = async () => {
    const activityData = await getActivityData();
    setActivities(activityData);
  };

  const setPolylineArray = async () => {
    const polylineArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
        const polylineData = activities[i].map.summary_polyline;
        const activityName = activities[i].name;
        const activityType = activities[i].type
        
        polylineArray.push({positions: polyline.decode(polylineData), name: activityName, activityType: activityType });
    }   // should push activity type as well
    setPolylines(polylineArray);
    //setIsLoading(false);
    console.log("Polyline array = ", polylineArray);
    console.log("polylines = ", polylines)
    setIsLoading(false);
}

    return (
        !isLoading && polylines ?
        <MapComp activityData={{polylines}? {polylines} : []} />
        : <div><p>Loading...</p></div>
    )

    
}


export default Mapp;
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty array is still a truthy value.

So the first time through

```
!isLoading && polylines ?
```

is true.

Either set the initial state of polylines to null instead of an empty array or check to see whether the the polylines array is empty before rendering <MapComp.

Comment: I set it to null and for some reason the same issue still occurs?

Comment: I have it working for a single piece of data that follows the same structure as above do you want me to edit the question and add that component to see if you can see what is missing I have tried comparing them multiple times now myself and cannot seem to find the issue